Should "pandemic" be capitalized when referring to "the pandemic"?
Writing about Covid-19, does the noun "pandemic" become capitalized?

There's a construction like "Capital P Pandemic" or "Capital B Beauty" that holds a philosophical meaning, perhaps specifying if it's the plutonic abstract version of specific practical version, I associate this usage with highly educated individuals from the 80s and 90s.

It would be unusual, though hardly unacceptable, to capitalise the pandemic (to emphasise the magnitude). Thus Conrad Duncan, writing under the Imperial College London aegis, writes:


Two years of COVID-19: What's next for the pandemic?


And Jamie Ducharme, in Time Magazine, March 2024, writes


[T]hese days, a lot of people refer to the pandemic in the past tense. “During COVID,” they say, or, “when we were in the pandemic.”
The implication is that the virus is gone and the pandemic is over.


So both capitalise (totally) the acronym but lower-case the word 'pandemic' even when obviously referring specifically to the COVID pandemic.
B Sawicka writing in NIH/NLM uses lowercase for coronavirus also:


The coronavirus global pandemic and its impacts on society ....


And Wikipedia has:


The official names COVID‑19 and SARS-CoV-2 were issued by the WHO on 11 February 2020 with COVID-19 being shorthand for "coronavirus
disease 2019".


It is interesting to compare and contrast the sentence here:


The Black Death was a bubonic plague pandemic occurring in Europe from 1346 to 1353.


[Again, Wikipedia]
But to show that capitalisation is not unknown for even the 'common names' ('Black Death' being stylised) of such major disease
occurrences, here is an extract from History.com:

... the “Great Pestilence” that was carving a deadly path across the
trade routes of the Near and Far East....
the pathogen responsible for the Black Death may have existed in
Europe as early as 3000 B.C. ....
The Bubonic Plague attacks the lymphatic system ....


Isn't there also a specific use of capitals as a way to 'turn up the volume'?  We do not usually write "Sorry, I've got a bit of a Cold today."  If anybody is writing about the difference between catching a cold and catching Covid.  It is my impression that cancer is normally written in lower case.  Is there any consistency in our use?  I doubt it.  Colds are endemic as covid may have become.  But we do not use the adjective 'endemic' as a noun.  But we do nominalise the the adjectives 'epidemic' and 'pandemic'.  We do say something is " important with a capital 'I' ".

Doesn't 'to emphasise the magnitude' say exactly this?

@Tuffy COVID-19 is capitalized because it's an acronym (of sorts), like HIV/AIDS, HPV, SIDS, SARS, etc. Writing it as Covid isn't quite correct, but it's common for acronyms to gradually lose capitals, especially if they're pronounced as words. We also capitalize medical conditions named after people (Down syndrome, Epstein-Barr) or places (Ebola, Lyme disease). It's not to do with importance.

@StuartF 'Isn't quite correct' is hyperprescriptive. RADAR is totally unidiomatic nowadays: it's what a significant proportion of people use that drives acceptability.

@ Edwin Ashworth:- Thank you for pointing out what I should have thought about.  I was, of course, following the spelling 'Covid' used in the question.  Nevertheless, I should say that (once the usage of initial uppercase has become established.  The Cambridge English dictionary entry Chooses "Covid-19" as the prime spelling and offers the alternative spellings "also Covid, COVID".  It does not offer all lower case as an alternative.

Short answer: it depends ...
The general rule is that proper names are capitalized, but not common nouns. So we write, "Fred Smith did this", capitalized, but, "The blacksmith did this", not capitalized.
If you gave a name to a pandemic, than it should be capitalized. Like, "During the Great Covid Pandemic of 2022 ..." If it's a generally recognized name, the case for calling it a proper name is stronger. Like, "The Great Depression" is almost always capitalized.
A name can be just a word or two. Like when we refer to the president of the United States, we often write, "the President".
So if you want to refer to the covid pandemic as "the Pandemic", that would be ... not necessarily "right", but not provably "wrong". My personal whim is that calling it "the Pandemic" is a little ... chauvinistic. There have been many pandemics in history. Just because this one is our own recent experience doesn't, in my mind anyway, raise it to the level of "the Pandemic" with a capital P. It surely does not compare to the Black Plague, etc. 50 years from now it will likely be a footnote in history. People who lived through it will be telling their grandchildren, "You don't know what it was like to live through the Great Covid Epidemic". And their reaction will be much like my reaction when my parents said to me, "You don't know what it was like to live through the Great Depression." Namely, "Yeah, mom. Whatever."
